# Image rollback using Raspberry Pi Bootloader

Tags: pi-3b+, bootloader, rpi-update, rpio, yocto

I'm using Yocto framework based RPi build and have created My SD card partition as follows,

======================== SD card with 3 parts ========================

| 68MB(bootloader)   |    4GB(Active image) |    4GB(passive image) |

==================================================================

I'm upgrading the image using from active bank partition to passive and after that modifying the cmdline.txt with my correct /dev/mmcbl0p3 value.

## Question:-

When new upgraded image is NOT booted properly, i have to rollback to my previous active image.

How to achieve this in bootloader? Is there any way to to recovery cmdline? is there any way to pass parameter to cmdline.txt file if NOT booted properly?

Suggestions and solutions are welcome..!!
Thanks in Advance..!!

Comment: Sound like a job for a second-stage bootloader like `grub2` which support scripts or extended configuration.

Comment: Yes, During bootloader time, i have to rollback if its not booting properly. Can you please explain about grub2 and how to use it. I'm new to grub2